# GCC Compiler optimization: Using character multiple times

Tags: c, gcc

When I use a character multiple times. For example `\"`, does gcc optimize this and only uses one reference? This character is used as a `const char` argument in a function.

The context: I use a couple of characters multiple times. I am thinking about replacing them with a const char and only use this variable. This would make the code a bit harder to understand, but if that optimizes the code size, I would consider doing it.

Comment: A character is a small number : would you replace all the numbers you write in your codes by constants ? I don't think it would be is any benefit to do that.

Comment: @dspr Depends on how many times the number is used. I write code for microcontroller. So, yes, it can make a difference on these devices.

Comment: Did you look at the generated code?

Comment: @CarlNorum Not yet. I also thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use a couple of characters multiple times. I am thinking about replacing them with a const char and only use this variable.

Any modern compiler is likely to produce the same code. You shouldn't worry about tiny literals like that, in some architectures they are inlined into the instructions themselves, yes, but referring to a common location is also going to take space.

Unless you have proven you have a need to optimize for that, it is not worth it.

> This would make the code a bit harder to understand, but if that optimizes the code size, I would consider doing it.

It depends. If it is meant to be a constant shared between those two lines, I would use a `const` or `#define`. If it is not meant to be the same (but just is by chance), then it doesn't matter. You could still use two constants in that case, giving proper names, which also helps to understand the code.

Comment: "but referring to a common location is also going to take space."
True that. Didn't thought about this part.

Comment: Having variables should in fact take more space than simply having them as literals.

Comment: @vmt Not really. The generated code is exactly the same.

Comment: @Acorn https://godbolt.org/z/a54P1o . Obviously it will be optimized out and it is used as a literal instead, but *in principle* it would only serve to increase size.